# How to make the browser display image with same name and not the cached one?

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have solved this with PHP by adding the 'time()' to the img src tag.

But how is it done with Javascript, same way?

Here is my code:

```
 th_div_html+= "<img src='"+path_th_img+"' class='shadow2' style='margin:7px;' onclick='imageShow("+z+");'>";
```

I'm better with PHP than javascript so I need your help on this one.

How can I add something like the 'time()' function to this img tag with javascript ?

Thanks

Comment: You would have to add the time value (`new Date().getTime()`) in the JavaScript that made the image src — presumably somewhere in `imageShow`, which you haven't shown us.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
img.src = 'img.jpg?' + Math.random();
```